Variables in Try-Catch blocks with Powershell?
I have been trying to write a script in powershell that renames a file if it does not get transferred correctly through WinSCP. The script looks something like this:
# Variables
$error = 0
$currentFile = "test"

# Functions
function upload-files {
    param(
        $WinScpSession,
        $LocalDirectory,
        $FileType,
        $RemoteDirectory
    )
    
    get-childitem $LocalDirectory -filter $FileType |
        foreach-object {
            # $_ gets the current item of the foreach loop. 
            write-output "Sending $_..."
            $currentFile = "$($LocalDirectory)$($_)"
            upload-file -WinScpSession $session -LocalDirectory "$($LocalDirectory)$($_)" -RemoteDirectory "$RemoteDirectory"
        }
}

try
{
    # Upload files
    upload-files -WinScpSession $Session -LocalDirectory [PathToLocalDirectory] -FileType [FileType] -RemoteDirectory [PathToRemoteDirectoy]
}    
catch
{
    Write-Host "Error: $($_.Exception.Message)"
    write-output $currentFile
    $errorMoveLocation = copy-item -path "$currentFile" -destination "$currentFile.err" -passthru
    Write-Host "Error File has been saved as $errorMoveLocation"
    $error = 1
}

I have removed the paths for ease of reading and some WinSCP lines that don't have anything to do with the issue.
When adding some script-breaking code after the upload-file function, it would go to the catch statement where I expected the $currentFile variable to be the $($LocalDirectory)$($_) since it was caught after setting the variable again. However, the actual value of the variable is the original "test" value that it was initiated with. I have tried changing the scope of $currentFile to both script, and global the same issue still happens. I am still relatively new at powershell and this is beyond my expertise. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

As written, there is indeed a variable scoping problem with your code:

(Non-module) functions (and script files) run in a child scope of the caller, so $currentFile = "$($LocalDirectory)$($_)" inside your upload-files creates a local $currentFile variable, that the caller doesn't know about, and which goes out of scope when existing the function.


I have tried changing the scope of $currentFile to both $script:, and $global: the same issue still happens

Using these scopes should work, given that you're explicitly specifying the target scope (and in the top-level scope, you don't even need the $script: scope specifier; also, $global: variables are best avoided, as they affect the global session state and linger after your script exits; while $script: is better than $global:, it is best to avoid cross-scope variable modification altogether.)
The only explanation for $script:currentFile = ... not modifying the value in the script / caller's scope would be if get-childitem $LocalDirectory -filter $FileType produced no output, in which case  the ForEach-Object script block is never entered.
Also note that at least in your upload-files function there is no code that would generate a terminating error, which is the prerequisite for being able to use a try {...} catch { ... } statement.

Ensuring the effectiveness of your try {...} catch { ... } statement:
Update:

You report that the nested call, to function upload-file (which isn't shown in the question) can generate a (statement-)terminating error, as a result of an exception thrown by a (WinSCP) .NET method call. Such a statement-terminating error is caught by an enclosing try { ... } catch { ... } statement, and control is instantly transferred to the catch block.
Note that without the latter, such a statement-terminating error by default does not abort the enclosing function; see the last of the two links at the bottom for more information.
Conversely, if you want continued execution despite using try { ... } catch { ... }, enclose the .NET method call too in try {...} catch { ... }, and translate the exception into a non-terminating error (try { ... } catch { $_ | Write-Error }), and combine that with method (c) below. (Of course, if you've ensured that no terminating errors can occur at all, you may dispense with try { ... } catch { ... } altogether.)

Your upload-files function only emits non-terminating errors, whereas try / catch only catches terminating errors.

Non-terminating errors are far more common than terminating ones.

To ensure that upload-files reports terminating errors, you have two options:

(a) Before calling it, (temporarily) set the $ErrorActionPreference preference variable to 'Stop', which promotes non-terminating errors to terminating ones.

Note: If your functions were defined in a module, this method would not work.


(b) Make your function an advanced (cmdlet-like) one, which makes it support the -ErrorAction common parameter , allowing you to pass -ErrorAction Stop on a per-call basis to achieve the same effect.

Decorating a function's param(...) block with a [CmdletBinding()] attribute is enough to make it an advanced one, and so is using a parameter-individual [Parameter()] attribute.



Alternatively, (c) - assuming you've made your function an advanced one - you can use the common -ErrorVariable parameter to capture all the non-terminating errors in a self-chosen variable (e.g., -ErrorVariable errs). If you find this variable non-empty, you can then use throw to emit a (script-)terminating error that catch will handle (e.g., if ($errs) { throw $errs }
Note that:

(a) and (b) by design abort processing (and transfer control to the catch block) once the first error occurs, whereas

(c) potentially runs the function call to completion, allowing potentially multiple, non-terminating errors to occur.



Implementation of (a):
$oldErrorActionPref = $ErrorActionPreference
try
{
    # Treat all errors as terminating
    $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
    upload-files -WinScpSession $Session -LocalDirectory [PathToLocalDirectory] -FileType [FileType] -RemoteDirectory [PathToRemoteDirectoy]
}    
catch
{
    Write-Host "Error: $($_.Exception.Message)"
    # ...
}
finally {
  $ErrorActionPreference = $oldErrorActionPref
}

Implementation of (b):
# ... 

function upload-files {
    [CmdletBinding()] # NOTE: This makes your function an *advanced* one.
    param(
        $WinScpSession,
        $LocalDirectory,
        $FileType,
        $RemoteDirectory
    )

    # ...
    
}

try
{
    # Pass -ErrorAction Stop to treat all errors as terminating
    upload-files -ErrorAction Stop -WinScpSession $Session -LocalDirectory [PathToLocalDirectory] -FileType [FileType] -RemoteDirectory [PathToRemoteDirectoy]
}    
catch
{
    Write-Host "Error: $($_.Exception.Message)"
    # ...
}


Implementation of (c):
# ... 

function upload-files {
    [CmdletBinding()] # NOTE: This makes your function an *advanced* one.
    param(
        $WinScpSession,
        $LocalDirectory,
        $FileType,
        $RemoteDirectory
    )

    # ...
    
}

try
{
    # Pass -ErrorVariable errs to collect all non-terminating errors
    # that occur, if any.
    upload-files -ErrorVariable errs -WinScpSession $Session -LocalDirectory [PathToLocalDirectory] -FileType [FileType] -RemoteDirectory [PathToRemoteDirectoy]
    # If errors occurred, use `throw` to generate a (script-)terminating
    # error that triggers the `catch` block
    if ($errs) { throw $errs }
}    
catch
{
    Write-Host "Error: $($_.Exception.Message)"
    # ...
}


See also:

The about_Try_Catch_Finally help topic.

A description of the fundamental error types in the context of guidance for command authors on when to emit a terminating vs. a non-terminating error: this answer.

A comprehensive overview of PowerShell's surprisingly complex error handling: this GitHub docs issue.



Thank you for the useful information! I'll give that a shot. I should've mentioned this in the OG post, but the upload-file line runs a function that just solely runs the PutFileToDirectory() method from the WinSCP .net assembly. That method does throw an exception. I intentionally left the script to continue on an error, so it skips over that  file and continues to the next in the directory. I hope that clears that up a little bit. Thank you again for the information!

Glad to hear it helped, @Evan, and thanks for the clarification (I've updated the answer). However, note that in the presence of an enclosing try {...} catch { ... }, the function that reports the .NET method exception (which in PowerShell terms is a statement-terminating error) instantly aborts execution and transfers control to the catch block. In other words: your function will not continue with the next directory. That only happens (by default) if there's no enclosing try {...} catch { ... }.

To avoid that, enclose the .NET method call  too in try {...} catch { ... }, and translate the exception into a non-terminating error (... catch { $_ | Write-Error }), and combine that with method (c).
